# Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine Prediction Input

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I have successfully trained and deployed a model for the CMLE.  There is a bit of a problem when I attempt to use it for prediction.
In my model, I have defined the serving input function as

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    def decode_and_resize(image_str_tensor):
        """Decodes jpeg string, resizes it and returns a float32 tensor."""
        image_str_tensor = tf.decode_base64(image_str_tensor)
        image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_str_tensor, channels=3)
        image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
        image = tf.image.resize_bilinear(image, [input_size[0], input_size[1]], align_corners=False)
        image = tf.squeeze(image, squeeze_dims=[0])
        image = tf.div(image, 255.0)
        return image

    input_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[None])
    images_tensor = tf.map_fn(decode_and_resize, input_ph, back_prop=False, dtype=tf.float32)

    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver({'input_1': images_tensor},
                                                    {'image_bytes': input_ph})
```

and for generating the json file, I went with

```
with open(json_path, 'w') as ff:
    for image_path in test_imgs:
        with open(image_path, 'rb') as image:
            img_bytes = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(image.read())
            row = json.dumps({'input_1': "name",
                              'image_bytes': {'b64': img_bytes.decode('ascii')}})
```

However, I always receive an error log

```
 error_detail: {
   detail: "Exception during running the graph: Invalid character found in base64.
     [[node map/while/DecodeBase64 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/ml/prediction/frameworks/tf_prediction_lib.py:210) ]]"    
   input_snippet: "{"input_1": "name", "image_bytes": {"b64": "_9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD_2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQ...   
  }
  message: "Exception during running the graph: Invalid character found in base64.
```

It seems that the engine isn't decoding the base64 encodings correctly?
I can get the prediction working if I encode the image directly, but then it would be very inefficient.